# How to choose a Instrumentation Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

For my project, I need to design a simple EEG circuit. As known, input signals are in micro volts.

After some research I understand that I should use an inst. Amp. to process the signal. Voltage gain should be 100.

The question is how I can choose the appropriate ins. amp ? 
Any help or guide will be appreciated.

Sincerely.

Comment: Usual voltage gain is more like 1:100,000 - if you can block the DC offset somehow.

Comment: Is there any source that we can see what component are okay for our specific purposes ?

Answer (score 1):

I would redirect you to consider the ADS1298  which has the Right leg drive (RLD)and everything else you need for ADC.

http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/slyt416/slyt416.pdf

> The ADS1294/6/8 are a family of multichannel, simultaneous sampling,
>   24-bit, delta-sigma (ΔΣ) analog-to-digital converters (ADCs) with a built-in programmable gain amplifier (PGA), internal reference and onboard oscillator. The ADS1294/6/8 incorporate all of the features that are commonly required in medical electrocardiogram (ECG) and electroencephalogram (EEG) applications

Comment: TI has the ADS1299 specific for EEG applications. ADS1298 has noise in one of the EEG bands - at least on our test bed.

Comment: oh? which band?